# Привязка обработчика к элементу массива

Tags: jquery

Мне надо привязать обработчики к 70 элементам, у которых нет id, но есть класс и обработчики будут разные. В общем, что-то типа:

```
$(".once_wrapper")[0].bind("click", function(){
    alert("Один обраб")
})
$(".once_wrapper")[1].bind("click", function(){
    alert("Второй обраб")
})
```

и так далее ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'bind'
```

Comment: тогда просто:

    var eventHandlers = [];
    eventHandlers.push(function(){
           alert("ds")
         })
    eventHandlers.push(function(){
           alert("dывавыs")
         })
    ...
    //добавляем в массив все необходимые обработчики в том порядке
    //в котором они должны быть навешены элемнтам
    //хотя я уверен, если различия не велеки, можно обойтись и без этого
    
    $(".once_wrapper").each(function(idx){
         $(this).bind("click", eventHandlers[idx]);
    })

Comment: "если различия не велеки, можно обойтись и без этого". В том то и суть - автор, скорее всего, просто видит неверное решение своей проблемы, либо просто не может ее нормально сформулировать (нужное подчеркнуть)

Comment: да там не alert() будет, я прото его написал, что-бы короче был код

Comment: @Zow - я это понял

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться, почему у элементов с одинаковым классом, должны быть столь разные обработчики? и в чём заключается основное отличие между ними? может эти различия проще запихнуть в data-атрибуты и от них уже отталкиваться, чем городить **70 раз**(!) один и тот же код

Comment: ну там идут как-бы картинки, на них щелкаешь и открывается плавающее окно с видео, которое хранится в ВК. Страница остается таже, просто добавляется новый див с фреймом видео от ВК

Comment: покажите пример реальной разметки пары картинок, и пару обработчиков кликов(нужно знать как вы открываете модальные окна и т.п.) и вам подскажут, как 70 обработчиков превратить в один

    <img class='once_wrapper' src='...' data-videoInfo='video1'/>
    <img class='once_wrapper' src='...' data-videoInfo='video2'/>
    etc...

js:
    
    $(".once_wrapper").bind("click", function(){
        alert($(this).data('videoInfo'));// эти данные можете использовать в своих целях
    });

"через src" тоже можно

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего - вам нужен вариант а ля `makeHandler`

@Zow задумайтесь над тем, что будет, если, допустим, вам нужно будет написать 100500 обработчиков. Если мыслить так, как мыслите вы - проще покончить жизнь самоубийством :D

Comment: а если через src находить, это тоже по быдлокодерски?

Comment: @Zow - я в полной степени не могу оценить вашу задачу, но, скорее всего - да

Comment: Мой совет - закройте текущий вопрос с подходящим ответом (или без него). Откройте новый вопрос в который покажите структуру из 2-3 картинок и с 2-3 обработчиками которые на них вешаете - там подскажут красивое решение задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $(".once_wrapper:first").bind("click", function(){
    alert("ds")
  })
})
```

От 0 до 70ого:

```
$(function() {
  $(".once_wrapper").slice(0,70).bind("click", function(){
    alert("ds")
  })
})
```

Если нужен цикл:

```
$(function() {
  var $els = $(".once_wrapper");
  for( var i=0; i<70/*$els.length*/; ++i ) {
    var $el = $els.eq( i );
    // .....
  }
})
```

Мде... таки с формулировкой вопроса большие проблемы. Собственно в части ответа про цикл уже таиться ответ, а именно:

```
  var $el = $els.eq( i ); // где i - ключ массива
  // т.е.
  $els.eq( 0 ).bind('click', function(){ alert(0) });
  $els.eq( 1 ).bind('click', function(){ alert(1) });
  $els.eq( 2 ).bind('click', function(){ alert(2) });
  // ....
  // но сразу предупреждаю - это быдлокод
```

###### что-то запамятовал я про eq

---

Если обработчиков действительно много ( скажем > 10), то примерно так, как предложил тов [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) в первом комментарии к вашему вопросу. Если-же меньше - задать идентификатор для всех элементов с разными обработчиками и атачить их явно с выборкой по id.

А если у вас обработчики схожие - напишите функцию, которая по тому или иному параметру будет возвращать обработчик. Что-то типа:

```
function makeHandler( index ){
   // тут как-то на основе индекса создаем нужный нам обработчик
   var handler = function(){ /*...*/ }
   return handler;
}
// соответственно потом получается что-то типа
$els.each(function( index ) {
   $(this).bind('click', makeHandler( index ));
})
```

А так, как пытаетесь решить проблему вы, явно не стоит делать. Причина очень проста - вы сильно привязываетесь к структуре DOM'а там, где это можно (и главное - нужно) избежать.

Comment: мне не к первому надо, а там будет много разных от 0 до 70

Comment: @Zow - это нужно отображать в своем вопросе.

Comment: обработчики тоже разные будут, ну вон я вопрос исправил

Comment: а может глянуть в сторону map?

Comment: зачем? по-моему элменты не нужно проецировать в какой-то другой результат, но учитывая как быстро меняется формулировка вопроса...

Comment: ну как я буду к разным элементам масива, в вашем цикле привязывать разные обработчики

Comment: ориентируйся на индекс, на имя, на id, на что-нть, что имеет вес. Спонтанно разные события же очень редко кто вешает.

Comment: @Zow, да как угодно

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а как решить эту задачу не по быдлокодерски?.
Так, как зделал @Spectre

Comment: $.each, просто не понятно как свои события различаете, какому элементу какой event.

Comment: "мне не к первому надо, а там будет много разных от 0 до 70" вот это вообще меня сбило с толку, я думал просто нужно атачить обработчики, но не для всех элементов :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы в скрипте пишите $(".once_wrapper")[0].bind(). $(".once_wrapper")[0] - таким способом вы получаете DOM элемент (а не jquery объект) и естественно у него нет метода .bind().

Для такой задачи замените конструкцию на $(".once_wrapper").eq(0).bind() - тогда возьмется первый  jquery объект из массива и присвоется обработчик.

Comment: по-моему ``$(".once_wrapper:eq(0)")`` эффективнее, это я для справки

Comment: нет, не эффективнее - работает гораздо медленнее (тоже для справки).

Comment: ещё раз взглянул в документацию

>For better performance use $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead

действительно, вы правы

Comment: Там такое написано? Признаться я этого не знал (про написанное). А быстродействие выборок пришлось тестировать опытным путем для проекта. В результате любые конструкции селекторов работали гораздо медленнее чем последовательные поиски. Так:

$(".once_wrapper a")медленнее $(".once_wrapper").find('a')

$(".once_wrapper:eq(0)") медленнее $(".once_wrapper").eq(0)

и т.п.